# Holomorphic subbundle and second fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

Setup: Let $E\rightarrow X$ be a holomorphic Hermitian vector bundle and $S\hookrightarrow E$ a holomorphic subbundle.

In Kobayashi's DIFFERENTIAL GEOMETRY OF COMPLEX VECTOR BUNDLES, in proposition 1.6.14 it says that the second fundamental form vanish if the complementary $S^{\perp}$ is holomorphic and the isomorphism
$$E=S\oplus S^{\perp}$$
holomorphic.

Now my question is, why is not it enough that $S^{\perp}$ is holomorphic? Is it possible that both $S$ and $S^{\perp}$ are holomorphic but the splitting is not? What can go wrong? In other words is there a situation where we cannot find a *holomorphic* retract to the map $S\rightarrow E$ ?

Comment: You always have the (smooth) decomposition $E=S\oplus S^\perp$. The question is: When we decompose a holomorphic section $\sigma = \sigma' + \sigma''$, with $\sigma'\in S$ and $\sigma''\in S^\perp$, are $\sigma'$ and $\sigma''$ holomorphic sections? (Almost never is the hermitian orthogonal complement of a holomorphic subbundle to be a holomorphic subbundle.)

Comment: @TedShifrin my question was assuming there exists a holomorphic complement, do we actually need the condition "there exists a holomorphic splitting" ?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely need it. Any time you have an exact sequence $0\to E' \to E \to E''\to 0$ of holomorphic vector bundles, it splits smoothly, but almost never holomorphically. (Homologically, working in the category of $\mathscr O_X$0-modules is very different from working in the category of $C^\infty(X)$-modules.) For a basic example, consider the Euler sequence for the tangent bundle of $\Bbb P^n$, even for $n=1$.